# Why is $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}^2=(-1)^{n/2}\binom{n}{n/2}$ if $n$ is even?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> Why is $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}^2=(-1)^{n/2}\binom{n}{n/2}$ if $n$ is even ?

The case if $n$ is odd, is clear, since $\displaystyle(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}+(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{n-k}=0$ (we have $(n+1)/2$ such pairs.)

but if $n$ is even we have no symmetry, I tried to consider the odd and even terms separately but with no success.

Do you have an idea ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Grigory M. but the answer here is much easier.

Comment: I don't see how Hagen von Eitzen's answer is any different from the first of two proofs by Marc van Leeuwen there — but if this helped you — great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_k (-1)^k{n\choose k}^2= \sum_k (-1)^k{n\choose k}{n\choose n-k}$$ is the coefficient of $x^n$ in 
$$(1-x)^n(1+x)^n=\sum_k{(-1)^k{n\choose k}}x^k\cdot \sum_k{{n\choose k}}x^k.$$
As $(1-x)^n(1+x)^n=(1-x^2)^n$, the claim follows (and we additionally see that $\sum_k (-1)^k{n\choose k}^2=0$ if $n$ is odd).

Comment: $(1-x^2)^n=\sum\limits_0^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k(x^2)^k$ and the coefficient of $x^n$ is at $k=n/2$, right ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}{n \choose k}^{2}
     =\pars{-1}^{n/2}{n \choose n/2}}$

> $$
> \mbox{Hereafter we'll use widely the identity}\quad
> {s \choose \ell} = \oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{s} \over z^{\ell + 1}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\tag{1}
> $$

\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}{n \choose k}^{2}}
=\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}{n \choose k}\
\overbrace{\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{k + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}
^{\ds{\mbox{See identity}\ \pars{1}}}
\\[3mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{-\,{1 \over z}}^{k}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z}
\bracks{1 + \pars{-\,{1 \over z}}}^{n}{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm]&=\pars{-1}^{n}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 - z^{2}}^{n} \over z^{n + 1}}
{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=\pars{-1}^{n}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{1 \over z^{n + 1}}\
\overbrace{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}z^{2k}}
^{\ds{=\ \pars{1 - z^{2}}^{n}}}\
{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm]&=\pars{-1}^{n}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{1 \over z^{\color{#00f}{\Large n\ -\ 2k}\ +\ 1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\pars{2}
\end{align}

> $$
> \mbox{However,}\quad
> \oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{1 \over z^{\color{#00f}{\Large n\ -\ 2k}\ +\ 1}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcl}
> 1 & \mbox{if} & n\ \mbox{is even and}\ n = 2k
> \\
> 0 && \mbox{otherwise}
> \end{array}\right.\qquad\qquad\,\quad\pars{3}
> $$

With $\pars{2}$ and $\pars{3}$, we'll find:
$$\color{#00f}{\large%
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}{n \choose k}^{2}}
=\color{#00f}{\large\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcl}
\pars{-1}^{n/2}{n \choose n/2} & \mbox{if} & n\ \mbox{is even}
\\
0 && \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.}
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $n=2m$ the problem becomes 
$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2m}(-1)^k\binom{2m}{k}^2=(-1)^m\binom{2m}m$

Now for non-zero finite $x,$

$\displaystyle(1+x)^n\left(1-\frac1x\right)^n=\frac{(1-x^2)^n}{x^n}(-1)^n$

Now compare the constant terms of the above identity.

Here $n=2m$