# finding the value of $\sum_k (-1)^k \binom nk^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I am trying to find the value of:
$$\sum_k (-1)^k {n \choose k}^2$$
The hint is that $(1-x^2)^n = (1-x)^n(1+x)^n$

I tried solving it using convolution but it didn't quite work.

Comment: Ow, sorry. That was a typo

Comment: is this a finite sum?

Comment: It's summing over all non-negative integers

Comment: your sum containes the Gamma-function

Comment: Looks an awful lot like [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/813925/11619). See, for example, Hagen von Eitzen's answer to the duplicate target in how to use convolution here. The trick is to replace the other $\binom n k$ factor with $\binom n {n-k}$.

Comment: Also, welcome to Math.Stackexchange. It was a bit of bad luck that your first question happens to have been handled already.