# Square sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I am a high school student and I am searching for a not very complicated way to calculate
$${100\choose 0}^2-{100\choose 1}^2+{100\choose 2}^2-{100\choose 3}^2+...+{100\choose 100}^2.$$

Comment: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180150/alternating-sum-of-squares-of-binomial-coefficients) gives you a way to proceed.

Comment: I searching for a simpler answer but thanks.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%20i%3D0%20to%20k%20%28%28-1%29%5Ei%20binomial%28k%2Ci%29%5E2%29%20and%20k%3D100

Comment: That's a really simple method though...   I don't know of a straight combinatorial interpretation of the result (though of course there might be one).

Comment: What *specifically* do you not understand about the answers in the linked question?  For what reason do you reject those answers and want a "simpler" approach?  How much "simpler" do you expect the answer to be?  $\binom{100}{50}$ is already simplified greatly.

Comment: As an aside, [this is the second time you asked this within the past hour](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3577581/what-is-the-sum-of-c100-02-c100-12-c100-22-c100-3?noredirect=1&lq=1).  You should not just repost the same question without addressing the issues that it was previously closed for.  Repeated violation of this is inviting consequences.

Comment: If the explanations on that answer are still unclear, then try going through the linked questions for additional explanations such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096873/sum-k-0n-1k-binomnk2-and-sum-k-0n-k-binomnk2?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813925/why-is-sum-limits-k-0n-1k-binomnk2-1n-2-binomnn-2-if?noredirect=1&lq=1) or others.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k {n \choose k}^2$$
$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} x^{k}~~~~~)1)$$
$$(1-1/x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k {n \choose k} x^{-k}~~~~~)1)$$
Multiplying (1) and (2), we get
$$(-1)^n (1-x^2)^n= \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k {n \choose k}^2 x^0+...+...$$ So $$S_n=[x^0] (-1)^n (1-x^2)^n=(-1)^{n/2}{n \choose n/2},~ if~ n ~  is ~ even$$
So the sum of the required series is $${100 \choose 50}$$

Comment: $n$ is $100$, not $200$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this.

Comment: Thanks for the help but there is a simpler solution?